# Market shares of Nested Logit demand model

Tags: supply-and-demand, demand, choice-theory

Consider a Nested Logit demand model with two nests, $N_1, N_2$: $N_1$ contains the outside option only (labelled "0"), $N_2$ contains all the remaining alternatives (labelled "$j=1,...,J$").

Suppose that the utility for consumer $i$ from picking alternative $j\in N_2$ is
$$
U_{ij}\equiv \delta_j+v_i+\lambda \epsilon_{ij}
$$
where $\lambda\in (0,1)$ and $(v_i, \epsilon_{ij})$ have a distribution which obeys the Nested Logit parametrisation.

Instead, the utility for consumer $i$ from picking alternative $0\in N_1$ is
$$
U_{i0}\equiv \epsilon_{i0}
$$

**Question**: could you help me to derive the market shares of a product $j\in N_1$ and of product $0\in N_2$?

I found the formulas for a generic nest structure (for example, [this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6670/how-to-derive-formula-for-marginal-probability-of-choosing-nest-in-nested-logit) question is helpful), but when I try to apply them to my very simple case they do not seem to simplify a lot.